# Is Github considered continuous integration? If not, what is the difference between Github and continuous integration?

Tags: github, continuous-integration

The Wikipedia definition of continuous integration is "the practice of merging all developer working copies to a shared mainline several times a day." How is this different than Github in which branches are merged into master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github is a tool which can be used for continous integration, The difference between the merging of branches into master is different to that of the CI. In CI all the developers will work merge their code daily into a branch(generally development) and this process essentially helps identifying the bugs quicker.  The branch will be configured for automatic testing and builds, this step although not needed generally implied.

More info:

https://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

https://codeship.com/continuous-integration-essentials

Comment: I understand now that continuous integration involves automated tests and possibly builds, whereas code merging in general does not imply that. Thank you for the links, they are educational.